# Cloud watch agent metrics for AWS ASG getting grouped event after instance deletion?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-auto-scaling, cloudwatch-alarms

> Background:

I am creating monitoring alarms for my AWS auto-scaling group. I have created the CPU utilization alarm using `Namespace: "AWS/EC2"` and `MetricName: "CPUUtilization"`, which is a built-in metric and alarm created on this metric works fine. However, for RAM(memory) utilizations I have installed Cloud Watch agent on the EC2 instances using the launch template. and using `Namespace: "CWAgent"` and `MetricName: "mem_used_percent"`.

> Issue

My issue is that cloud watch agent metrics stays in cloud watch metrics even after auto scaling group terminates the instances and since my alarms are on the basis the dimension of auto scaling group, I do not get the metrics because it tries to group the metrics even for the instances that have been deleted already. Below screenshot would help you to understand better. **I know we cannot delete cloud watch metrics**. However is there a way to ask the cloud watch alarms to only group the metrics for currently running instances? Or any other possible solutions? Thank you for your time and help.

> Cloud Watch agent metrics

[image]

> RAM/Memory Alarm

[image]

> CPU Utilization Alarm
> [image]
>
> amazon-cloudwatch-agent.json

```
{
  "metrics": {
    "aggregation_dimensions": {
      "AutoScalingGroupName": "\${aws:AutoScalingGroupName}"
    },
    "metrics_collected": {
        "disk":{  
        "resources":[  
          "/"
        ],
        "measurement":[  
          "used"
        ],
        "metrics_collection_interval": 60
      },
      "mem": {
        "measurement": [
          "mem_used_percent"
        ],
        "metrics_collection_interval": 60
      }
    }
  },
  "logs": {
    "logs_collected": {
      "files": {
        "collect_list": [
          {
            "file_path": "/var/log/messages",
            "log_group_name": "$log_group_name",
            "log_stream_name": "$log_stream_name",
            "timezone": "UTC"
          },
          {
            "file_path": "/var/www/logs/app.log",
            "log_group_name": "$app_log_group_name",
            "log_stream_name": "$app_log_stream_name",
            "timezone": "UTC"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "log_stream_name": "cloudwatch-agent",
    "force_flush_interval": 5
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your cloudwatch agent json file and the Alarm details of for memory alarm?

Comment: Sure I would, later. Because I believe I know what wrong and working on it currently.

Comment: I have read and tried a lot on this and came to the conclusion that we cannot create a single alarm for namespace CWAgent using dimension as autoscalinggroup. One possible solution is creating alarms for each instance using lambda(this is supported using the CWAgent namespace) and then creating a composite alarm for all these alarms.

Comment: Are you aggregating all the metrics from your ASG instances? In the json config file, do you have `"aggregation_dimensions" : [["AutoScalingGroupName"]]`? `The metrics from all instances in each Auto Scaling group are aggregated and can be viewed as a whole.` Because it looks to me that you don't have an aggregated metrics. See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch-Agent-common-scenarios.html#CloudWatch-Agent-aggregating-metrics

Comment: I have edited the question to add the complete Cloud Watch agent configuration in json

Comment: I have tried "aggregation_dimensions" : [["AutoScalingGroupName"]] as well and this did not help